# i'm not able to acces DataFrame by loc

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Team             2000     2001   2002     2003
lecce             2        2       1        2
bari              6        8       8       16
roma              0       13       0        0
milano           10        6       0        0
```

then i  set team like index:

```
data_read.set_index('Team',inplace=True)
```

if i try to access to Dataframe using:

```
data_read.loc['lecce'][0],
```

i get `"KeyError:0"`

how can i fix it?

Comment: The error is because you have no column called `0`, what are you trying to actually do? If you just want that row then `data_read.loc['lecce']` should just work, if you want the first column then `data_read.loc['lecce', 2000]` or `data_read.loc['lecce', '2000']` should work

Comment: Not quit clear about your question . what you want to achieve

Comment: Remove the `[0]`

Comment: Oh I see, you want the first column (by position). Do ````data_read.loc['lecce'][data_read.columns[0]]````

Answer (score 1):

Using `data_read.loc['lecce']` returns the single row of your data frame with the index equeal to `'lecce'`.  The object that is returned is not a list.

You need to index it using the column names.  To access the first element of the first row, use:

```
data_read.loc['lecce', 2000]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already got a correct answer, but you can also use the same syntax as you use in your example, like this:

```
data_read.loc['lecce']['2000']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first column (by position), use:

```
data_read.loc['lecce'][data_read.columns[0]]
```